# Returning the JSON representation of a String with Jersey

Tags: java, javascript, json, dojo, jersey

I'm about to setup a REST-Webservice with Jersey.
At the moment I am a bit confused about the correct representation of Strings or other Value types in JSON.
Here are two snippets:

```
@GET
@Path("user")
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User user() {
    return new User("reini", "admin");
}
```

Calling this method in a Browser will display a "good" JSON String like that:

```
{"name":"reini","role":"admin"}
```

My second method looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("hello/{name}")
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String hello(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return "Hello " + name + ", it is " + new Date();
}
```

Calling that method in a Browswer will display a pure String without any JSON-Stuff (Curly Braces etc):

```
Hello firefox, it is Tue Sep 18 13:52:57 CEST 2012
```

I want to consume this service with the dojo toolkit. The problem is, that I get an for the second method as soon as I set [handleAs: "json"]-flag. It throws me an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token H" where "H" is the first letter of the returned string.

So: What is the correct json representation of Strings and other value types and what annotations I have to set for my method to produce these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define a `DTO` and put your `String` in that. So you will hava a `HelloResp` class with one String as attribute. In your method populate that attribute and return.

You can check this [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggrby/index.html). Another [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html).

Firefox is not showing error because, it is not processing your response. Whatever is returned by service is displayed. The toolkit however starts processing the reponse as a JSON but did not a valid JSON (JSON starts with `{`)

Comment: is it better to create a DTO for every operation or to create a DTO for each type I want to use?

Comment: "JSON starts with {" - Incorrect. According to http://json.org even a quoted string literal is valid JSON, and jersey should support correctly serializing a string as a JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

If you are returning a String why do you define it as a type JSON?

Just return it as a plain text (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN):

```
@GET
@Path("hello/{name}")
@Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return "Hello " + name + ", it is " + new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also return it as:

```
@GET
@Path("hello/{name}")
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String hello(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return "\"Hello " + name + ", it is " + new Date()+'"';
}
```

but it's look very strange for me.

Creating DTO for every object also looks strange just for one String.

Is there any better option?

Comment: Can you please explain why you are using a double quote? ("") instead of just : return "Something" ? I'm having an issue with that and dont understand why a regular string is not converting to a valid json response

Comment: Reason is that this returns MediaType Application Json and you could manualy return some json as "{\"a\": 1}" which is not a string. See aproved answer